# File Shows error

Tags: ruby, file, mod-rewrite

while inserting the content to a file:

```
    file1=File.new("output.txt","w+")
    puts "enter the string"
    in1=gets.chomp
    if file1
            file1.syswrite()
    else
        puts cant write
    end
    file1.close
```

Comment: What error? Why lowlevel `syswrite`?

Comment: past the error please

Comment: i need to write the content to the file which is currently in the in1...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses the `write` method on the [File class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html). Remember when you're writing a puts statement, the succeeding String needs to be in quotes.

```
file1=File.new("output.txt","w+")
puts "enter the string"
in1=gets.chomp
if file1
  file1.write(in1)
else
  puts "can't write"
end
file1.close
```